# Why these two shapes behave differently when scaled up using align to pixel grid?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes, transform

See image 1 below.

- Orange shape has a width of **38px** and a thickness of **1px**, with a radius of **12px**
- Green has a width of **152px** and a thickness of **1px**, with a radius of **3px**

I created these shapes using the technique in image **4**.

There are two rectangles one over the other, and I used the `MINUS FRONT` **Pathfinder** command to create these two shapes of the same height but different widths and radii.

[image]

My **problem occurs** when I try to enlarge these shapes.

---

**Behavior 1 (image 2):** I enlarged each of them individually to **200%**. The green shape maintained a correct thickness (2px) but radius got distorted, and the shape became a straight line. The orange shape maintained every aspect.

---

**Behavior 2 (image 3):** When I enlarge both of the shapes together, both shapes maintained their proportions and nothing got distorted.

---

Why is that?

I need to maintain the pixel perfect ratio and enlarge without losing/distorting the radius. Is this something to do with the RADIUS / RADIUS-WIDTH RATIO?

---

Generally, is it even possible to maintain the proportions of such shapes given that align to pixel grid is checked?

Comment: 1. what you call height is simply the thickness of the stroke, or the stroke itself (it's clear that the green shape is higher than the orange one). 2. did you finish the boolean operation (merge shape components) or is the shape you used to subtract still part of the objects?

Comment: another question: are you scaling just the height or width+height proportionally?

Comment: 3rd question: are you using photoshop or illustrator? you added both tags. I'll assume Illustrator.

Comment: 1. These are shapes, not strokes. 2. They are not part of anything else. They are independent. 3. I maintained proportions. 4. Illustrator

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: I tried to reproduce it too, but can't.

Comment: @Luciano @ Billy Kerr even I can't produce it now. I guess it was bug in that version of illustrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Modify the inner curve or move the bottom point a pixel down:

[image: curve]

[image: Point down]

[image: Pixel Down]

Comment: Hi, I can't move it a pixel down as I don't have to change radius. Further I was more interested in knowing the reason for this behavior.